# How to send and retrieve from methods

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to send and retrieve values since I have object oriented my code, in the Addition.xaml I am trying to send the 'AddLevel' variable which is an int, in the Addition.xaml I have:

```
private void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Methods.AddLevels(AddLevel, Question1,Question2, Answer);
   QuestionText1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Question1);
   QuestionText2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Question2);
}
```

In this method I am trying to send the AddLevel int variable to the Methods class to determine what to do, in the Methods class I have:

```
public static int AddLevels(int AddLevel, int Question1, int Question2, int Answer)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    if(AddLevel == 0 || AddLevel == 1)
    {
       Question1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
       Question2 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
       Answer = Question1 + Question2;
    }

    return Question1;
    return Question2;
    return Answer;

}
```

Just to summarize, I am trying to send the AddLevel from the Addition.xaml to the AddLevels method in the Methods class, then I am trying to retrieve the Question1, Question2 and Answer from this method. How do i do this?

Comment: Three `return` statements after each other? What do you expect will happen here? Your first `return` statement returns Question1, the other two `return` statements are ignored.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I understand, hence why I am asking for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a `Tuple`:

```
private void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<int, int, int> result = Methods.AddLevels(AddLevel, Question1, Question2, Answer);
    QuestionText1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(result.Item1);
    QuestionText2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(result.Item2);
}

public static Tuple<int, int, int> AddLevels(int addLevel, int question1, int question2, int answer)
{
    if (addLevel == 0 || addLevel == 1)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        question1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        question2 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        answer = question1 + question2;
    }
    return Tuple.Create(question1, question2, answer);
}
```

Another option yet less recommended is to use the `ref` keyword:

```
private void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Methods.AddLevels(AddLevel, ref Question1, ref Question2, ref Answer);
    QuestionText1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Question1);
    QuestionText2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Question2);
}

public void AddLevels(int addLevel, ref int question1, ref int question2, ref int answer)
{
    if (addLevel == 0 || addLevel == 1)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        question1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        question2 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        answer = question1 + question2;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Tuple` might be appropriate for a one-time scenario. However, also consider simply declaring a type specific for the purpose, especially if this combination of values is useful for longer than just receiving the return value from the method. Note that as far as passing by-reference, `out` is a better choice than `ref` when the parameters are only being assigned as here.

Comment: Also, when using `Tuple`, I recommend taking advantage of the static `Create()` method: `return Tuple.Create(question1, question2, answer);`

Comment: Good comment. Recommendation added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect. BTW add the closing bracket to the Tuple.Create :) Also @PeterDuniho could you please explain why it is better to use Create()

Comment: Whops. Typo fixed :-)  In regards to the `Create` method: that's a helper method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383822(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JermainDefo: it's "better" just in the sense that it makes the code easier to write and read. The alternative requires specifying each individual type used in the `Tuple`, but when using the `Create()` method, the compiler will infer the types from the arguments passed, saving some typing and making the code more-expressive/less-verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Build your method to return Dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> AddLevels(int AddLevel, int Question1, int Question2, int Answer)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    if(AddLevel == 0 || AddLevel == 1)
    {
       Question1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
       Question2 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
       Answer = Question1 + Question2;
    }

    dic.Add("Question1", Question1);
    dic.Add("Question2", Question2);
    dic.Add("Answer", Answer);

    return dic;

}
```

When you want to take the value of Question1, Question2, Answer, just write it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = AddLevels(AddLevel, Question1, Question2);
int question1 = dic["Question1"]; // this will return the value for Question1.
```

One of the requirement for Dictionary is the `Keys` to be unique, you should guarantee that. In your case keys are : `"Question1", "Question2", "Answer"`.

You should write your parameter names with starting with small letter: `addLevel, question1, question2` and etc.

Comment: When the key names will always be the same, IMHO a dictionary is too heavy-weight. Just use a simple data-container type like `Tuple` or type declared specifically for the purpose (as in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems like you're over complicating things to avoid binding? AddLevels seems like it easily be a part of a DataContext?

**SomePage.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="QuestionText1" Text={Binding Question1} />
<TextBox x:Name="QuestionText2" Text={Binding Question2} />
```

**SomePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SomePage : UserControl
{
    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new SomePageViewModel();
    }

    private void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((SomePageViewModel)this.DataContext).AddLevels(AddLevel);
    }
}
```

**SomePageViewModel.cs**

```
public class SomePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Answer
    {
        get { return _answer; }
        set
        {
            if (_answer != value)
            {
                _answer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Answer");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Question1
    {
        get { return _question1; }
        set
        {
            if (_answer != value)
            {
                _question1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Question1");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Question2
    {
        get { return _question2; }
        set
        {
            if (_question2 != value)
            {
                _question2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Question2");
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddLevels(int addLevel)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        if(addLevel == 0 || addLevel == 1)
        {
           Question1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
           Question2 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
           Answer = Question1 + Question2;
        }
    }
}
```